# Can't seem to import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

Tags: java, compiler-errors, importerror

I have the following very simple java file called test.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
```

and when I run

```
javac test.java
```

I get the following error

test.java:1: cannot find symbol
   symbol  : class RecursiveAction
   location: package java.util.concurrent
   import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
                           ^
   1 error

and if I run java -version I get

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
```

also if I try javap -verbose anotherfile I get that

```
major=50
```

so it seems like a must be using java 6.

I'm probably missing something frustratingly silly nevertheless I can;t see what it is.

Comment: What does `javac -version` produce?

Comment: javac 1.6.0_30 and therefore this must be my problem.

Comment: indeed, have posted solution below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely you are using a JDK earlier than JDK 7 and a JRE that does actually use version 7 which is required for the class. Solution: install JDK 7 which should update the PATH environmental variable - remove the earlier JDK from the PATH

Answer (score 2):

[`java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html) was only introduced in JDK7 (see the `@since` annotation in the Javadoc), so if you were to compile your code against an earlier version of the JDK (6 or below) then you would get an error message like this.

Comment: Does 1.7.0_25 mean I have JDK7 installed? And if it does how do I tell the compiler to use JDK7

Comment: Yes. You configure your PATH variable so that the JDK7 compiler is before any other `javac`s.